# Card tile grid like google plus

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, material-ui, css-grid

How to create card tile scrolling grid like google plus, with three columns? I am using Material UI, but I cannot find such a functionality? I have tried standard Material ui grid, but it is not working.

Comment: It's not clear what are you talking about. Check masonry (https://masonry.desandro.com/) to see if it is the thing you are looking for?

Comment: @webgodo https://plus.google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a **masonry** grid. It's currently impossible to do so in pure CSS, even with the new grid layout mechanism ([[1]](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/945), [[2]](https://github.com/rachelandrew/cssgrid-ama/issues/19#issue-201073253)).

Material UI doesn't offer an out-of-the-box solution for masonry grids.

You might be interested in some of the many JavaScript libraries which arrange elements this way using a custom script. The most popular one which immediately comes to mind is [**Masonry Desandro**](https://masonry.desandro.com/). An alternative is [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/), a payed library for commercial use, which also has [a mode for masonry layout](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html).

Comment: why would this not be possible in pure css? doesn't flex box do this?

Comment: The standard masonry layout, no. Please look at GitHub issues I've provided as a reference.